# Как из большого текстового файла вытащить необходимые данные?

Tags: python, анализ-данных

столкнулся с такой проблемой: Есть огромный текстовый файл, из него нужно вытащить необходимые данные и построить из них таблицу. Пробовал уже всеми известными мне способами - ни в какую.

Отрывок из файла:

```
"ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 3 (обязат
ельное). НОРМЫ
РАСХОДА ВОДЫ ПОТРЕБИТЕЛЯМИ
ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ 3
Обязательное




 Нормы расхода воды, л                        Расход    воды
                                                                               прибором,   л/с
                                                                               (л/ч)


в     средние в сутки         в час
                                  сутки         наибольшего     наибольшего
                                                водо-           водо-
                                                потребления     потребления
Водопотребители        Изме-    общая    горя- общая горя-   общая горя- общий            холод-
                       ритель   (в том   чей (в том чей      (в том чей  (холод-          ной
                                числе          числе         числе       ной              или
                                горячей)       горя-         горя-       и горя-          горячей
                                               чей)          чей)        чей)
                                                                                               ,
                                                                                      (
                                                                                          (            ,
                                                                                  )
                                                                                                   )


1                      2        3       4     5      6       7      8     9               10


1.   Жилые      дома
квартирного типа:


с водопроводом и 1              95      -     120    -       6,5    -     0,2 (50)        0,2 (50)
канализацией  без житель
ванн


с газоснабжением       то же    120     -     150    -       7      -     0,2 (50)        0,2 (50)


с      водопроводом, "          150     -     180    -       8,1    -     0,3             0,3
канализацией       и                                                      (300)           (300)
ваннами            с
водонагревателями,
работающими       на
твердом топливе


с      водопроводом, "          190     -     225    -       10,5   -     0,3             0,3
      канализацией и                                                      (300)           (300)
в а н н а м и      с
г а з о в ы м и
водонагревателями


с                  "            210     -     250    -       13     -     0,3             0,3
быстродействующими                                                        (300)           (300)
газовыми
нагревателями    и
многоточечным
водоразбором"
```

На выходе хочется получить таблицу из представленных чисел записанную в xlsx формате. Пожалуйста, подскажите, какое решение лучше для этого применить?
Язык: Python

Comment: судя по примеру данных, приведенных в вопросе ваш файл не имеет ничего общего с CSV форматом...

Comment: Файл изначально был сконвертирован из pdf, подправлю вопрос, это обычный текст

Comment: Вы пробовали другую версию найти? Например, [тут](https://expert-01.com/biblioteka/normativnye_dokumenty/Snip/Pril/2-04-01-85_03.htm) та же таблица в удобочитаемом виде.